# Scala error: value $ is not a member of object org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext

Tags: scala, shell, apache-spark

I'm new to Spark. I'm trying to run the following code in Spark shell:

```
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext
import org.apache.hadoop.conf
JavaSparkContext context = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
<console>:32: error: value context is not a member of object 
org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext
val $ires10 = JavaSparkContext.context
                           ^
<console>:29: error: value context is not a member of object 
org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext
     JavaSparkContext context = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
```

Is there any import statement that I'm missing? I also added

```
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext._
```

but it still didn't work. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**: Whether the configuration is valid or not is something you'll have to work on, but this addresses the error you asked about in your original question.

Your code is (almost) valid *Java*, but not valid *Scala*. Did you mean something like this:

```
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext

val context = new JavaSparkContext()
```

Alternatively, since you're using *Scala*, you might want to try this instead.

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext

val context = new SparkContext()
```

As for the error you report, *Scala* will treat the statement `JavaSparkContext context` as a reference to a member named `context` of an `object` named `JavaSparkContext` - and not as a variable declaration as it is in *Java*.

Comment: I did try that earlier, but I got an error saying <console>:38: error: package org.apache.hadoop.conf is not a value

Comment: That's probably because `org.apache.hadoop.conf` is a package, not a configuration instance. You need to determine how to create the object that you pass to `JavaSparkContext`'s constructor.